# Using protractor + appium run android app test

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I have configured all setup required for protractor + appium 
this here is my conf.js file

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

  specs: ['first.js'],

  // Reference: https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/node/helpers/caps.js
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    platformName: 'Android',
    platformVersion: '7.0',
    deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000'
};
```

but i dont know how should i locate mobile app using script

or if i'm going wrong plz help me out with protractor + appium to test my first Android app...

Answer (score 1):

Protractor **does not support native Android** apps: [proof link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1798#issuecomment-340017419).

With protractor you can mobile sites in browser or hybrid app that starts with WebView (by adding `autoWebview: 'true', autoWebviewTimeout: '10000'` in your config)

You want to test native Android app you need to use other client libraries:

1) [**wd.js**](https://github.com/admc/wd)

2) [**webdriverio**](http://webdriver.io/)

Comment: thanks for reply,  here what i want to do is to test mobile a demo mobile app, but unable to locate the mobile app it opening chrome browser inside mobile ?

Comment: Once again: you can test any web site suing your configuration, protractor will start browser. You cannot run mobile app, e.g. Facebook, it just don't support it.